# Change password of AWS RDS during cloning

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have my production database with some specific master password and a specific user. My database is AWS RDS with PostgreSQL.

I'm automatically cloning it every day to some *dev* environment, where I need multiple developers to have access to it, but they should not have access to the *production* environment.

How can I give it a new, non-production password during cloning? I can obviously use some automatic tool I can write. But I prefer something simpler, or optionally to use AWS API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IAM to provide access to any RDS instance without having to share any passwords.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html